# Why am I able to SSH a remote machine even with the wrong keys?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, key-authentication

## Description

I have created an `ssh` connection between my MS-Windows PC and Raspberry Pi. To do so I followed the following steps:

Step 1: Somehow get the IP address of the Raspberry Pi. It should be something like this: 192.168.1.52

Step 2: Open a shell and access the Raspberry Pi via ssh:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.52
```

You will need the password.

Step 3: In the home directory of the remote pc use these commands:

```
mkdir .ssh
```

Step 4: Secure the ssh connection via private/public key. In the local pc use this commands:

```
ssh-keygen -f .ssh/fede_windows -t rsa -b 4096
```

If your local machine is Linux based run this line:

```
chmod 600 .ssh/fede_windows # if linux
```

Finally:

```
scp .ssh/fede_windows.pub pi@192.168.1.52:.ssh
```

Step 5: In the remote pc use these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and modify the following lines of the config file:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Finally:

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd
```

Step 6: In the remote computer use these commands:

```
cat ~/.ssh/fede_windows.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Step 7: In the local computer run this command to log in to the remote one:

```
ssh -i .ssh/fede_windows pi@192.168.1.52
```

**Problem**: When I perform all these steps again in my Ubuntu Pc by generating this time a key named fede_ubuntu, it looks like that I am able to ssh my Raspberry Pi no matter what I insert in the command:

```
ssh -i .ssh/fede_xyz pi@192.168.1.52
```

It works all the time and this is not supposed to happen since it should be restricted only to the key I just created. If I switch to my Windows machine everything works as expected and only if I specify the right key works.

**Question**: Would you be able to suggest a possible reason of this issue and how to fix it please?

**EDIT**: By typing the following command `ssh -i .ssh/key_that_does_not_exits -v pi@192.168.1.52` I get:

```
Warning: Identity file .ssh/key_that_does_not_exits not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.52 [192.168.1.52] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.52:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hC5w2kDxgHH5eFRY1vOJaS7ipPR+8OWX2tkkEZbF194
debug1: Host '192.168.1.52' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/federico/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: federico@federico RSA SHA256:E96Hu2Ee+IyAuoZ06GxTvo+ZmAkzqfihbAKkFqxU1AU agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/federico/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: federico@federico RSA SHA256:E96Hu2Ee+IyAuoZ06GxTvo+ZmAkzqfihbAKkFqxU1AU agent
debug1: Server accepts key: federico@federico RSA SHA256:E96Hu2Ee+IyAuoZ06GxTvo+ZmAkzqfihbAKkFqxU1AU agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.52 ([192.168.1.52]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = it_IT.UTF-8
Last login: Sun Aug 22 22:26:00 2021 from 192.168.1.197
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your log:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: federico@federico RSA SHA256:E96Hu2Ee+IyAuoZ06GxTvo+ZmAkzqfihbAKkFqxU1AU agent
debug1: Server accepts key: federico@federico RSA SHA256:E96Hu2Ee+IyAuoZ06GxTvo+ZmAkzqfihbAKkFqxU1AU agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

This means that a key from your SSH agent is being used.  I'm assuming it's a valid key that you have recently used and that you have either manually added to the agent, or that has been added due to using `AddKeysToAgent yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Remove all identities from your SSH agent and try again: `ssh-add -D`.  Alternatively, add `IdentityAgent none` to your SSH configuration or use `ssh -o IndentityAgent=none` when you call `ssh`.

You may also benefit from using `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your SSH configuration, which will give you more control over exactly which identities are offered to an SSH server.  See the documentation for this option in `ssh_config(5)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if I can set IdentityAgent none in some config file in the remote computer? Somewhere like in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?

Comment: @FedericoGentile No, this is strictly an option for the client. The server (`sshd`) does not know what provides it with a key for authentication, nor why a particular key is provided.  The option stops the client from providing _all_ available keys to the server if an explicit key has been configured for the connection.

Comment: Ok perfect thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

ssh cannot find the key which you suggested with the -i option so it tries the other available keys. You have a valid key in the .ssh directory which  is accepted and the connection is made.  If you do not want that key to be used delete it or secure it with a passphrase so that you have to supply the passphrase to allow the connection.

You are not connecting with the "Wrong Key", the key it has used is in your .ssh directory and is valid for the connection.

Comment: Setting `PasswordAuthentication=no` and `IdentitiesOnly=yes` in the local `.ssh/config` (or via the command line, via `-o ...`) may prevent a user from inadvertently using pasword auth or some identity she hasn't explicitly specified when connecting to some server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if I can set IdentityAgent none in some config file in the remote computer? Somewhere like in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?

Comment: If you place the keys in a location other than ~/.ssh then the ssh service won't be able to find them, it will only be able to use the one you ask it to use or fail.